# Draggable droppable on the same class

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, drag

I've a droppable div "container" and draggable div elements of class "event" inside it.

I would like to drag/drop .event into .container, but not on/into other .event.
It's like in a calendar, no event can be at the same time/day.

To achieve my goal I tried to use 3 different ways, but maybe I'm missing something because no one works:

1  - Set .event elements to be draggable and, at the same time, droppable not accepting ".event" as draggable.

```
$(".event").draggable({
containment : "parent",
zIndex : 100,
grid: [60,30],
revert: "invalid"
}),

$(".event").droppable({
accept: ".nothing",
tollerance: "touch",
greedy:true
}),

$("#cont").droppable({
accept:".event"
})
});
```

2  - similar to above but forcing revert with over/out functions

```
$(".event").draggable({
containment : "parent",
zIndex : 100,
grid: [60,30]
//revert: "invalid"
})

$(".event").droppable({
accept: ".event", //".nothing",
tollerance: "touch",
greedy:true,
over: function(e,ui) {
    $("ui-draggable-dragging").draggable("option","revert",true);   
},
out: function(e,ui) {
    $("ui-draggable-dragging").draggable("option","revert",false);  
}
})
/*$("#cont").droppable({
accept:".event"
})*/
});
```

3 - I tried to change the class of draggables to avoid draggable/droppable with same class name (in case this could be the problem).

```
$(".event").draggable({
start : function(e,ui) {
 $(".event").addClass("event2");
 $(".event").removeClass("event");
 $(this).addClass("event");
 $(this).removeClass("event2");
},
stop: function(e,ui) {
 $(".event2").addClass("event");
 $(".event2").removeClass("event2");
}
})
```

Someone could help me to find a solution? This is the original code:

```
<style>
#main {
 width: 360px;
 height:360px;
 margin-top:0;
 position: relative
}

 .container {
  width:360px;
  height:360px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:url('grid3.gif');
  <!-- grid3.gif is a 30X60 grid background -->
}

.event {
width:58px;
color: white;
background-color: #cc0000;
margin:0;
padding:4;
font-size: 8pt;
font-family: 'Arial';
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
z-index : 2;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.event2 {
width:58px;
color: white;
background-color: #cccccc;
margin:0;
padding:4;
font-size: 8pt;
font-family: 'Arial';
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
z-index : 2;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".event").draggable({
containment : "parent",
zIndex : 100,
grid: [60,30]
})

$("#cont").droppable({
accept:".event",
});

});



<div id="main">
 <div class="container" id="cont">
  <div class="event" id="1" style="height:90; top:0px; left:0px;"><p>ev1</p></div>
  <div class="event" id="2" style="height:30; top:90px; left:0px;"><p>ev2</p></div>
  <div class="event" id="3" style="height:120; top:30px; left:180px;"><p>ev3</p></div>
 </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Please avoid using inline styles, especially mixing inline and external styles... [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: Since you said *"calender like"* - will there be an column (*`<div>`*) to represent the empty space as well..? if so, you can solve this easily.

Comment: @TJ container is the grid of the calendar and .event are the events themselves... so "empty space" is everything not filled by .event

Comment: @TJ I know that inline styles aren't the best, but .event divs are created dynamically(via php): height,top and left are different for every div... I didn't find a better solution :( Every tip is really apreciated. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/0f5yqwxL/) providing following possible solution

```
$(".event").droppable({
    accept: '.event',
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        console.log("drop on child");
        $(ui.draggable).animate({
            "left": "0"
        }, "slow");
    }
});
```

In case an `.event` is dropped in an `.event`, the dropped `.event` animates to the left. This has to be adjusted - e.g. to avoid to animate the dropped `.event` onto another `.event` - , e.g. with setting the original position of each `.event` as data-attribute on the draggable divs and animate back to the original position when dropped in an `.event` - but just wanted to share the suggestion as it's possible you want to proceed somehow else when `.event` is dropped in `.event`.

**Update:** This is working in Firefox and IE11, but just was informed by TJ (see comment below) that it's not working in Chrome.

**Update 2:** As asked for in the comments below, now reverting to original previous position - [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/0f5yqwxL/1/):

```
$(function () {
  $(".event").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    zIndex: 100,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("stopped draggable");
        $(this).data("top", $(this).css("top"));
        $(this).data("left", $(this).css("left"));
    },
    grid: [60, 30],
  });

  $("#cont").droppable({
    accept: ".event"
  });

  $(".event").droppable({
      accept: '.event',
      greedy: true,
      revert: "valid",
      drop: function (e, ui) {
        console.log("drop on child");
        $(ui.draggable).animate({
            "left": $(ui.draggable).data("left"),
                "top": $(ui.draggable).data("top"),
        }, "fast");
      }
    });
});
```

**Update 3:** Just installed Chrome, for me it's also working there. I'm on Win7, tested in Firefox 32, IE11, Chrome 37 without any issues. As mentioned in the comments, there could be issues but can't reproduce.
As suggested by Bux in the comments, it would be better to adjust the setting of the values of the current position to "start" instead of "stop", so it would be (only relevant above code here)

```
$(".event").draggable({  
....
start: function (event, ui) {  
....
```

instead of `stop: function (event, ui) {`

Maybe this'll also fix the issues mentioned by TJ.

Comment: @TJ Maybe a misunderstanding - you can drag it, but not drop it on the item. Only checked with Firefox, is the item droppable for you on another item? If so, which browser?

Comment: I just dropped `ev2` and `ev3` into `ev1`. I can only see `ev3` now. I'm using latest version of chrome.

Comment: @TJ Thanks for the input, I updated this in the answer. Just tested it with IE (working).

Comment: @Matthias - your solution works, no more dropping on other .event object, but I was trying to revert the dragged item (when dragged on onther one) to its orginal position.. so using revert = true. Is this possible?

Comment: @Bux Yes, as mentioned I'd suggest to set the original position to each item as data-attribute, initially and also when dropped at a droppable place, so that the call to animate animates the item back to the saved previous position. But, as TJ mentioned, it's not working in Chrome, so maybe not the best approach (?). I've to check if the "original" revert-option for droppable works, than the suggested adding data-attributes for position won't be needed.

Comment: i did the same thing in `IE11` as well... and it logs *"drop on child* not sure how it works for you and doesn't work for me 0.o

Comment: @TJ It's even more weird - I just installed Chrome and for me it's working - I'm on Win 7, don't know if that could be an issue, but there has to be a difference as it's not working for you.

Comment: @matthias_h: To have items returning to their original position is better to use a START function instead of the STOP one... so when start dragging I know which was the original position and not the "dropped" one. Now it's working for me on IE11, Firefox and Safari... will check for Chrome

Comment: @Bux Thanks, think you're right. Just tested it with "stop" as I thought there could be issues with the timing (e.g. that in the "stop" the dropped position is written and therefore the animate won't work), maybe it'll also work for TJ when used in START instead.

Comment: @matthias_h: also tested in Chrome..OK. I've found a small issue... when you have .event div of different heights (even if I add external css ex. #2 {height: 30px;} ) ev1 and ev3 are droppable on ev2, if height of ev2 is more then 30px everything is ok... do you know why?

Comment: @matthias_h: sorry, i've not seen that tollerance : "touch" was removed in your answer;)